# Writing data from an R data-set into Redshift

Tags: r, amazon-redshift

I am connecting R to amazon Redshift using the package "RPostgreSQL" I can connect, create and delete tables, query the database, save the data into an R data-frame and manually insert values.

What I cannot do is insert data into Redshift reading directly from an R data-frame and I can not use the dbWriteTable function due to missing Posgress component in redshift.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Without having any experience with Redshift, I think you will more likely get an answer if you provide some sample code or a (minimal) example that doesn't work.

Comment: @Speendo The code I'm running is:
install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
library("DBI")
library("RPostgreSQL")
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
redshift_con <- dbConnect(drv2, credentials here....)
r_c_100 <- dbSendQuery(redshift_con ,"select * from public.dc_c limit 100")
r100 <- fetch(r_c_100,n=-1)
dbWriteTable(redshift_con,"newTable",r100)

Comment: @speedo The error I'm getting is: 
Error in is(object, Cl) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 'dbWriteTable': Error: object 'con' not found

Comment: sorry, I cannot help you with this problem. But maybe somebody else can work with this, especially if you add this information to your question.

Comment: @speedo Actually just found the solution, is not optimal for large volumes but works.
It useS "RODBC" package and the command sqlSave(). But you need to set up a odbc connection in advance.

Comment: Are you running R local or running server?  Cleaner option might be to push your data frame into S3 then use COPY command into Redshift. Kinda safer that way as well. There is a bunch of tools out there than can take your file and sync it to S3 bucket which is far more stable way to go and won't bog down your IDE for half an hour with such a small amount :)

Comment: Thanks @digdeep, I was Testing from local but actually using S3 is the only solution, I am trying to get some code to sent a PUT to the S3 API and than use the copy command from R. I will probably approach some other tool to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Just solve it myself using RODBC package.

You need to set up an ODBC connection let's call it i.e. redshift_con.
From R than you need to create a connection (i called it ch) using:

```
ch <- odbcConnect("Annalect DB", uid = "username", pwd = "******")
```

loaded my dataframe in R and runned:

```
sqlSave(ch, mydataframename, addPK = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```

And R creates a new table in redshift called "mydataframename". It's not really fast, I'll keep you updated if I find and optimized method.

If you need more information see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html

```
################ SAMPLE CODE FOR TESTING ##############
install.packages("RODBC")
library('RODBC')
ch <- odbcConnect("redshift_con", uid = "admin", pwd = "********")
sqlColumns(ch, "public.r_test")
USArrest<-data(USArrests)
sqlSave(redshift_con, USArrests, rownames = "State", addPK = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```

I'll post a comment on the process speed.

UPDATE

Good only for VERY small amount of data

half an hour for 1500 records.