# How do I set up the ODBC connection in R?

Tags: r, odbc, amazon-redshift

This is a follow up question to this thread.

[Writing data from an R data-set into Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783571/writing-data-from-an-r-data-set-into-redshift)

How do I set up the ODBC connection in R? In other words, where I enter the details such as

driver, url and port?

Answer (score 1):

Following the referenced question, if you are on Windows, you create a user DSN or system DSN ODBC connection in the ODBC data source administrator (search for ODBC in the search box of the start button). Then you use this name on the second line of the following code. Where it says `"mydsn"`.

```
library(RODBC)
myconn <-odbcConnect("mydsn", uid="Rob", pwd="aardvark")
crimedat <- sqlFetch(myconn, "Crime")
pundat <- sqlQuery(myconn, "select * from Punishment")
close(myconn)
```

If you haven't got the Amazon Redshift ODBC drivers installed, you will have to install them first. I found a link [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

I created a class to encapsulate the connection. First, you have to setup odbc data sources 64bits (depending of the database driver). After that, I create a new class with setRefClass:

```
library(odbc)
library(methods)

MyDatabaseConnection <-
  setRefClass("MyDatabaseConnection", fields = list(conn = "ANY"))
MyDatabaseConnection$methods(
  initialize = function() {
    conn <<- dbConnect(
      odbc(),
      dsn = "your data source name from odbc",
      uid = "your user",
      pwd = "Your password")
    )
  },
  finalize = function() {
    if (is.null(conn) == FALSE) {
      conn <<- NULL
    }
  },
  query = function(sql) {
    if (is.null(conn) == FALSE)
    {
      dataf <- dbGetQuery(conn, sql)
      print(class(dataf))
      return(dataf)
    }
    else
    {
      print("No connection")
    }
  }
)
```

You can create an object from this class

```
my_conn <- MyDatabaseConnection$new()
```

You can run the function which returns a data.frame

```
data <- my_conn$query("SELECT * FROM TABLE")
```

This class will help you to organise much better and tidy up your code.